# What's wrong with my XPath in the CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to fetch the date information in the [link](http://www.twse.com.tw/en/trading/exchange/STOCK_DAY/genpage/Report201401/201401_F3_1_8_9921.php?STK_NO=9921&myear=2014&mmon=01), so I'm using the CasperJS. I analyzed the XPath of the date:

```
//*[@id="contentblock"]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[position()>=3]/td[1]/div
```

My casperJS script is as below:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["includes/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"]
});
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

var myear = casper.cli.get(0);
var mmon  = casper.cli.get(1);
var stk_no = casper.cli.get(2);

casper.start('http://www.twse.com.tw/en/trading/exchange/STOCK_DAY/STOCK_DAYMAIN.php', function() {
    this.fill("form[name='date_form']", {
        'myear' : myear,
        'mmon'  : mmon,
        'STK_NO': stk_no
    },true);
});


casper.waitForUrl(/Report/,function() {
    var xPathRes = document.evaluate ( '//*[@id="contentblock"]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[position()>=3]/td[1]/div', document, null, 0, null);
    this.echo(xPathRes);
    var nodes = xPathRes.iterateNext();
    this.echo(nodes);
    while (nodes)
    {
        this.echo(nodes);
        this.echo(nodes.innerHTML);
        nodes=xPathRes.iterateNext();
    }
});

casper.run();
```

With the command line

```
casperjs mytest.js 2014 1 9921
```

My script gave me the response:

```
[object XPathResult]
null
```

It seems that `xPathRes.iterateNext()` returned null, which means no matched xpath. I'm not sure what's wrong with my XPath and script. Could anyone give me some hint on this problem?

I've tried XPath:

```js
var xPathRes = document.evaluate('//*', document, null, 0, null);
this.echo(xPathRes);
var nodes = xPathRes.iterateNext();
this.echo(nodes);
while (nodes)
{
    this.echo(nodes.tagName);
    nodes=xPathRes.iterateNext();
}
```

and the result was

```
[object XPathResult]
[object HTMLHtmlElement]
HTML
HEAD
BODY
```

I thought it will give every element in the html.

Another try:

```js
var xPathRes = document.evaluate('//*[@id="contentblock"]', document, null, 0, null);
this.echo(xPathRes);
var nodes = xPathRes.iterateNext();
this.echo(nodes);
while (nodes)
{
    this.echo(nodes.tagName);
    nodes=xPathRes.iterateNext();
}
```

and the result was

```
[object XPathResult]
null
```

It seems that it didn't match anything. It's weird because the element with **id=contentblock** does exist if I dump the html with

```js
this.debugHTML();
```

---

The code using CasperJS API below works. But using document.evaluate fails. It's quite weird. I don't know how should I debug this.

```js
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.waitForUrl(/Report/,function() {
    this.test.assertExists(x('//*[@id="contentblock"]/td/table[3]'), 'the element exists');
    this.echo(this.getHTML( x('//*[@id="contentblock"]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div') ,true));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried testing the XPath step by step? Should be easy enough to find the point at which it stops to return anything.

Comment: I have tried some xpaths as my added description. It was weird '//*[@id="contentblock"]' won't work.

Comment: Part of the web page you try to scrape is dynamically generated. Maybe that already fails. Try to turn on debugging and/or output the web page HTML as casper sees it so you can have a look at it.

Comment: Actually I've dumped the HTML with this.debugHTML(); so I think I output the web page HTML. I don't know what's happening there.

Comment: I'm at a loss. The only thing I have left to recommend is to start with `x("/*")`, then `x("/html")`, `x("//*[@id]")`, `x("//*[@id] > ''")` and so on, adding one feature at a time to the XPath expression. Of course testing on a different machine/with a different web page, too.

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS has two distinct contexts. Since CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS, it has the same limitation. You can only access the DOM from the page/DOM context. The [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) provides this access, but the function that you pass into it is sandboxed as seen in the PhantomJS [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html).

You cannot call `document.evaluate` outside of `casper.evaluate()`, because `document` has no meaning outside of the page context. I don't know why `document` even exists in casper context, because it doesn't do anything. Actually, the outer context has a dummy page which consists only of `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` which explains the limited results that you see.

If you wrap this in `casper.evaluate` then you cannot pass DOM elements to the casper context anymore, because only primitive objects can be passed in and out. If you want to access the elements you may use [`casper.getElementsInfo`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) depending on what you want to do with it.

```js
casper.waitForUrl(/Report/,function() {
    var xPathRes = this.getElementsInfo('//*[@id="contentblock"]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[position()>=3]/td[1]/div');
    xPathRes.forEach(function(element, index) {
        this.echo(element);
        this.echo(element.html);
    });
});
```

You can also do your stuff in page context, but then you have to keep in mind what kind of representation you can to and from the page.

```js
casper.waitForUrl(/Report/,function() {
    var elements = this.evaluate(function(){
        var xPathRes = document.evaluate ( '//*[@id="contentblock"]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[position()>=3]/td[1]/div', document, null, 0, null);
        var collectHTML = [];
        var nodes = xPathRes.iterateNext();
        while (nodes)
        {
            collectHTML.push(nodes.innerHTML);
            nodes = xPathRes.iterateNext();
        }
        return collectHTML;
    });
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(elements));
});
```